# risk on selling home and never receiving funds from settlement company

Tags: united-states, mortgage, fraud, home, title-insurance

I was about to sell a home where I have good equity, my question is what are the chances that settlement company never pays me the proceeds and runs away/abscond.

I see there is FDIC insurance for protections against Bank Fraud, SIPC for protection against brokerage failure. So what is the protection does a seller have against settlement company.

A **second** way of asking could be
How to verify that settlement company is not a fraud ?

a **third** way for same question.
How to verify the legitimacy of settlement company ?

A **fourth** way.
Will my title insurance cover the loss if during the sale, the settlement company abscond with money.

Comment: Isn't this a problem for the *buyer*? Until *you* (and/or your mortgage lender) have the cash in hand, I don't think the transaction is complete.

Comment: You might simply look to see if the company has a history of doing business.  I just looked up the title company I dealt with most recently.  It's not likely that a company doing about $5.8 billion worth of business is going to abscond with your money.

Comment: @jamesqf where to verify that, a title company (if fraud) can make any claim. So just like for FDIC, we can go to fdic.gov and verify. What about settlement company ?

Comment: @chepner please look at comment that I am just going to add after this

Comment: Here is what the settlement company says **The timing of the receipt of your proceeds will be dependent upon several factors. On the day of closing, once we have completed the buyers' portion, then we will take the next steps to get authorization from the lender in order to submit the appropriate documents to the courthouse. Once we are on record with the county, then we will be in a position to disburse funds.**

Comment: @puzzled: If they're a public company, you should be able to find all sorts of records, maybe vis the SEC.  Or as in my case, you could consider the fact that they've had their name on several largish office buildings in town for the last several decades.

Comment: @jamesqf  with BANKS , we have all sorts of records, should FDIC be abolished ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Mutual had several largish office buildings and they filed chapter 11

Answer (score 2):

The real estate laws are state laws. I picked Virginia as an example.

In Virginia this is regulated by the state corporation commission. The position is [Real Estate settlement Agent](https://scc.virginia.gov/getdoc/403a6237-2a15-4dee-a2be-57aa224cb990/resafaqs.pdf).

> **Registration/Licensing related questions**
>
> 1.Who is required to be registered?
>
> Any person, other than the lender, seller, purchaser or borrower, who
> conducts the settlement conference and receives or handles money, must
> be registered. See Virginia Code § 55.1-1000 and Chapter 395, Rules
> Governing Settlement Agents, Regulation 14VAC5-395-10 through
> 14VAC5-395-90.

There is a [procedure for registering](https://scc.virginia.gov/pages/Real-Estate-Settlement-Agents-(RESA))

> Step 1
>
> Apply for a Virginia Title Insurance Agent or Agency license.
>
> Step 2
>
> Obtain an appointment with an insurer in Virginia.
>
> Step 3
>
> Secure each of the following insurance coverages. On the RESA
> application you must attest that you have and will keep the following
> for as long as you are a Real Estate Settlement Agent:
>
> - An Errors and Omissions insurance policy (E&O) or Malpractice policy with a limit of at least $250,000
> - A Blanket Fidelity Bond or Employee Dishonesty insurance policy in the amount of at least $100,000 per occurrence or claim. Settlement
>   agents with no employees except the owners, partners, shareholders, or
>   members may request a waiver of this requirement on their RESA
>   application or submit the Waiver Form later.
>
> Step 4
>
> Purchase a Surety
> Bond in the amount of $200,000 from an authorized surety company. The
> surety company must use the official Surety Bond Form.
>
> Step 5
>
> Register
> as a Real Estate Settlement Agent via Sircon. On Sircon, the
> application is referred to as a Title Settlement Agency/Agent
> application. The nonrefundable application fee is $100 for an agency
> and $35 for an agent. Note: Agencies must register their business with
> the Clerk’s Office of the Virginia SCC before submitting their RESA
> application.
>
> Step 6
> Mail the original Surety Bond to the following
> address:

The state also provides a way to verify the license of an agent, and lookup any complaints.

Specifically addressing the 4 questions:

> 1. So what is the protection does a seller have against settlement company.

The state licensing and the requirement for insurance and a bond. They are required to have this coverage.

> A second way of asking could be How to verify that settlement company is not a fraud ?

They are licensed by the state. The government has a way for you to check on their history You should be able to see the history of complaints against the company. When deciding to use a settlement company you need to check the information they give you regarding their license.

> a third way for same question. How to verify the legitimacy of settlement company ?

Again the state government through the appropriate licensing agency.

> A fourth way. Will my title insurance cover the loss if during the sale, the settlement company abscond with money.

There are two title insurance policies. The one that is required by the lender is only there to protect the lender. If they get their money they don't care about the rest of the transaction. So if the settlement attorney sends the payoff money to the old lender they are fine.

The second type of policy is optional and protects the homeowner. You will have to review the documents to see when coverage stops, and what protection do they have regarding the equity.

Comment: @mhoran-psprep if a company is listed with State Corporate Commission, it only verifies that at one point company registered, but does not make transaction secure . There has been instances where **Bernie Madoff** and **Ponzi schemes** are done by companies that are registered.

Comment: If they have acted honestly in the past their insurance policy would have kicked in, the state would have been notified and the they could even lose their license and their bond.

Comment: @mhoran-psprep with logic that in past ... , then in past ** https://www.quora.com/Why-and-when-did-Countrywide-go-out-of-business ** was doing right, but FDIC was needed to be kicked in

Comment: If the state government, an insurance policy, and the threat of jail doesn't satisfy your requirements what would?

Comment: @mhoran-psprep if fraud happens with Bank, does not state government, threat of Jail etc not occure, so why FDIC?